# Windows installer project - control progress bar from within custom action

Tags: c#, windows, installation, progress-bar

How do I control/update the UI progress bar when running length custom actions on a C# deployment project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the MSI interfaces are C++ based and that there is no .NET support for native MSI capability and you won't be too surprised to see this, C++.

See following:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367525%28VS.85%29.aspx